# Applying a template to a Custom Post Type Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to apply a template to a `Custom Post Type` in `Wordpress`. Currently I am displaying a list of `Custom Post Types` on a seperate page and I'm using the `permalink` for each post as the `URL` to go to when a link is clicked.

Code to generate the links:

```
<a href="<? echo get_post_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
```

This redirects me to a page with a `URL` like this:

```
http://xxx.xxx/?pa_supplier=xyz-packaging-ltd
```

I am wondering how I could customize how this page might look.

I know for `pages` you can create a `php` file called page-id.php and subsitute the page id in and that will allow for customization, can something similar be done to `Custom Post Types`?

Comment: Put a file in Root of your current theme and its name should be single-customposttypename.php  
dont forget to put your custom post name at the place of "custompostypename"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a new template file in the theme folder and name it with following syntax: single-[post-type_slug].php, for example. If we have a post-type named "projects", the file for displaying a single projects post would be "single-projects.php".

Check the following link for more information:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy